# Swift UITableViewCell without Storyboard don't use Auto layout

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I'm trying to write a UITableViewController without Storyboard with a class that defines the UITableViewCell.
I configured the table view as required with

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 200.0  
tableView.register(HomeCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
```

and created a `HomeCell` UITableViewCell class with only an icon.

```
override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    icon = UIImageView(frame: CGRect.zero);
    icon.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    contentView.addSubview(icon)
}
```

I inserted in the class the func for Auto layout and controlled, with debug, that the function is called:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    icon.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    icon.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    icon.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor,
                               constant: 5).isActive = true
    icon.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor,
                              constant: 5).isActive = true
    contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: icon.bottomAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
}
```

The result is that I have the icon in the correct position but the `contentView` has a wrong height, that is the original size of 44 set by UITableViewAutomaticDimension, and consecutive rows overlaps.
Someone have any idea of what is wrong?

Comment: bottom anchor `isActive` is missing?

Comment: layoutSubviews gets called multiple times, your code effectively add same set of constraints multiple times which is anyway not needed, so rather move all your constraint adding code to init

Comment: Sorry, was a bad copy but the result is that the content view is of the same height and the icon was compressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should activate the constraints a

```
override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    icon = UIImageView(frame: CGRect.zero);
    icon.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    contentView.addSubview(icon)
    setContr()
} 
func setContr() {

    icon.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    icon.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    icon.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
    icon.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
    contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: icon.bottomAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
}
```

Comment: That is the correct solution. I activate the constraints in the controller with <code>setNeedsLayout</code> but if the cell was created the height remains the same. In this way the cell is created with the correct height. Many thanks